# Why am I not getting the wright values when sending my form?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I am new to .NET and bad at English.
This is the code for my form. Currently, I am only getting the value for productName but I need to get the value for "category" too. "category" remains to be Null when the controller is called. What am I doing wrong? Can anyone give me a hint here?

```````
<form asp-controller="Products" asp-action="ByCategory" method="get">
                <div class="col" style="margin: 4px 10px 12px 1px">
                    <div class="input-group" mt-2>
                        <input type="text" name="productName" class="form-control" placeholder="Serch by name" />
                        <div class="input-group-append">
                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Search" />
                        </div>
                    
                        <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" name="category" 
                                id="category" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"
                                style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 10px">
                            Categories
                        </button>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="">

                            @for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++)
                            {
                                <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">@ViewBag.Data[i]</button>
                            }

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
   </form>
``````

and here is the code for my controller
``````
        public async Task<IActionResult> ByCategory(string category, string productName)
        {
            
                var model = _context.Product.Where(p => p.Name.Equals(productName)).Select(p => new ProductViewModel
                {
                    Id = p.Id,
                    Name = p.Name,
                    Price = p.Price,
                    Count = p.Count,
                    InventoryValue = p.Count * p.Price,
                    Category = p.Category
                });
                return View("ByCategory", await model.ToListAsync());
        }
``````
```````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.Form submit cannot automatically post the button value. You need set a hidden input and use jQuery to set the input value when you choose the dropdownlist.

2.Model Binding binds the property by name attribute. You need set `name="category"` for the hidden input.

Here is a whole working demo:

```
<form asp-controller="Products" asp-action="ByCategory" method="get">
                <div class="col" style="margin: 4px 10px 12px 1px">
                    <div class="input-group" mt-2>
                        <input type="text" name="productName" class="form-control" placeholder="Serch by name" />
          //add hidden input here..
                        <input type="text" name="category" id="category" class="form-control" hidden>

                        <div class="input-group-append">
                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Search" />
                        </div>                        
                        <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" name="category" 
                                id="category" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"
                                style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 10px">
                            Categories
                        </button>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="">
                             @for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++)
                             {
                                 <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">@ViewBag.Data[i]</button>
                             }    
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
   </form>    
@section Scripts
{
    <script>
        $("button.dropdown-item").click(function(){
            $("#category").val($(this).text());
        })

    </script>
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works perfectly with the changes that you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment you have defined one input for your form
`<input type="text" name="productName" class="form-control" placeholder="Serch by name" />`

You should also define a second input for `category` so that it will also be submitted with the form.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer. The value for category comes from this drop down button. <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" name="category" 
                                id="category" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" ...